# How can I inserting a string with a single quote in it into a DB2 table?

Tags: db2

I'm using a DB2 database.

How to insert `'` (single quote) as data into a table.

For example:

```
Insert into EMP values ('Raju's kumar' , 10000)
```

where the name has a `'` (single quote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (double quote)

```
Insert into EMP values ('Raju''s kumar' , 10000)
```