# How can i create a ' character in Sql?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

i am trying to concatenate a generated string with an ' how can this be done? I#m looking for something like

```
--result: 'abc'
values '''' || abc || '''';
```

Comment: follow this .https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-given-string-can-be-generated-after-concatenating-given-strings/

Comment: That doesnt worked out :(

Comment: This actually seems to work. Can you clarify why exactly this isn't satisfactory?

Comment: Database message (partly german):

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
values "'" || 'abc' || "'"

[SQL0206] Spalte oder globale Variable ' nicht gefunden. [SQL State=42703, DB Errorcode=-206]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.53s

Comment: Your error message says `"'" || ...`, but your code example says `'''' || ...`.

Comment: @ScootCork: double quote are for identifiers, not for strings in SQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I inserting a string with a single quote in it into a DB2 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174958/how-can-i-inserting-a-string-with-a-single-quote-in-it-into-a-db2-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the EBCDIC characters with their hex values:

```
values x'7D' || 'abc' || x'7D';
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention German in a comment...

IIRC, | is not one of the EBCDIC invariant characters

Try using CONCAT instead.

```
values '''' CONCAT abc CONCAT '''';
```